# Error message "cannot convert from 'const GLfloat [12]' to '_Objty'" when inserting 2D array into std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have this 2D array of GLfloats:

```
static constexpr GLfloat facenormals[6][12] = {
    {
        0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // TOP
    },
    {
        0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, // BOTTOM
    },
    {
        0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, // FRONT
    },
    {
        0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, // BACK
    },
    {
        1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, // RIGHT
    },
    {
        -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, // LEFT
    }
    };
```

and an `std::vector<GLfloat>`. My goal is to add the data from one of the sub-arrays of my 2D array to the end of the vector. My first attempt was this:

```
normals.insert(
    normals.end(), 
    &CubeData::facenormals[direction], 
    &CubeData::facenormals[direction] + 12
);
```

But when building the solution I get the error "cannot convert from 'const GLfloat [12]' to '_Objty". I tried changing the arguments of the `insert()` call to this:

```
normals.insert(
    normals.end(), 
    CubeData::facenormals + 12 * direction, 
    CubeData::facenormals + 12 * (direction + 1)
);
```

but I get the same error when compiling.

How do I do this correctly, and what does the error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Objty` is the name for the vector's type parameter in MSVC's particular implementation of the standard library. So the compiler is telling you you can't convert a value of type `GLfloat[12]` to whatever the vector is storing.

But why were you trying to insert arrays?

The problem lies in those extra `&` in the call to `insert`. This'll fix it:

```
normals.insert(
    normals.end(), 
    CubeData::facenormals[direction], 
    CubeData::facenormals[direction] + 12
);
```

`CubeData::facenormals` is an array of arrays, so `CubeData::facenormals[direction]` is an array. That would normally decay in a pointer automatically, which would give you what you want, but by prepending a `&`, you instead get a pointer to that array. That pointer gets dereferenced into an array.

By removing `&`, you let the array decay to a `GLfloat*`, and then that gets dereferenced into something that you can assign to a `GLfloat`.

Comment: The array is static containing data that will be used, and the vector contains an unknown amount of the sub-arrays in an unknown order. The data in the array will later be passed to a vertex buffer on the GPU to be processed by the shader. Is there another way you see that would achieve this more effectively?

Comment: If the data is static, why do you need to make a copy before you pass it to the GPU?

Comment: The only other way to do it as I see it is to instead of copying the parts of the data I store references to the static data in the order I want, but I don't know how to pass all of the references to the GPU buffer at once. the call to transfer the data to the GPU takes a reference to one  block of memory and copies a specified amount from that blocks starting position. If there is multiple references to what would be the same block of static memory, I would need multiple transfer calls. 

If you are good at using OpenGL and could make it work without copying, please tell me